# Circuitikz connections: connecting ball (*-) , plus turning a corner (-|)

Tags: circuitikz

There’s got to be a better way!  And, I’m sure someone here can show it to me.

I often find myself wanting to make a connection in a schematic, where one end of the connection should have that circular dark blob that you get with the * for an inline short.  The other end of the connection is around a corner somewhere.  That is, you have to draw two orthogonal lines to get there -- normally done with the “down and over” operator |- or its twin -|.

But, the to[short, *-] inline element doesn’t seem to work with the |- operator.  So, I end up drawing a tiny short for .1 cm or so, and then the “down and over” portion.  Like so:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[american,RPvoltages,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{logic ports=ieee}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\node [and port] (and0) at (0,2) {and0};
\draw (and0.in 2) -- ++(-1,0) node[left] {$A$};
\draw (and0.out)  -- ++(1,0) node[right] {$B$};

\node [or  port] (or0)  at (3,0) {or0};
\draw (and0.in 2) to[short, *-] ++(0,-.1)
                  |- (or0.in 1);
\draw (or0.in 2) -| ($(and0.out) + (0,-.1)$)
                  to[short, -*] (and0.out);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

This gives me the following drawing:
[image: Two gates with two connectors]

You can see that I’ve done the connectors two ways, depending on which end I want the connecting circle to show up.  But, neither method is elegant.

What I want is a notation where I can do something like:

```
... to[short, *-] |- (or0.in 2);
```

But, that doesn’t work.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `to[]` does not work with `|-` or similar. You have to think at `to` as a fancy `--` (a line/wire with something added in the middle; in the case of `short` nothing is added in the middle). This is not `circuitikz` specific; you can try with Ti*k*Z `to[out=45, in=135]` and see...

The best way is to do the connection with plain lines and add the pole with `node[circ]{}`, or to use perpendicular *coordinates* instead of *movements*.

An example of the first option is to use

```
\draw (and0.in 2) node[circ]{} |- (or0.in 1);
```

for your first connection (basically is the same that `*-` is doing under the hood), and the second one could be applied to your second connection:

```
\draw (or0.in 2) -- (or0.in 2 -| and0.out) to[short, -*] (and0.out);
```

Also, you can put poles at arbitrary positions along `--`, `-|` or `|-` line operation; one nice thing is that in a `|-` or `-|` operation, the "kink" is at `pos=0.5` (see the code I added to your example).

```latex
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[american,RPvoltages,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{logic ports=ieee}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\node [and port] (and0) at (0,2) {and0};
\draw (and0.in 2) -- ++(-1,0) node[left] {$A$};
\draw (and0.out)  -- ++(1,0) node[right] {$B$};

\node [or  port] (or0)  at (3,0) {or0};
\draw (and0.in 2) node[circ]{} |- (or0.in 1);
\draw (or0.in 2) -- (or0.in 2 -| and0.out)
    to[short, -*] (and0.out);

% You can "drop" a pole in several positions in a |- or -|
% path, either by using the default position for "nodes on the path"
% positioning...
\draw (4,2) node[circ]{} -|        % this is at pos=0
    node[circ, color=blue]{} (5,0) % this is at pos=0.5
    node[circ, color=red]{};       % this is at pos=1
% or explicitly with `pos`
\draw (4,1.5) -| (4.5, 0)
    node[pos=0, circ]{}
    node[pos=0.5, circ, color=blue]{}  
    node[pos=1, circ, color=red]{};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  Really great stuff.  I had no idea about the pos trick -- seems very useful.